# Optional fields in form with expressjs

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I actually work on a school project, I have to do a dating website with a micro-framework.
I choose to use ExpressJS to learn NodeJS, but I have some struggles with the asynchronous...
I try to make a profile update form where you have to put you're old password to update your e-mail address or your password or both on one form. But with the asynchronous i don't know how to validate the form.

We can't use ORM, validator or user manager (like passport).

Here is what i tried

First route to the form

```
router.get('/profile', isConnected, (request, response) => {
     response.render('profile.ejs');
});
```

Second route to validate the form

```
router.post('/changeCredentials', isConnected, (request, response) => {
     var user = User.formJSON(request.session.user);

     if (User.hashPassword(request.body.old_password, user.salt) === user.password)
     {
         if (request.body.email !== undefined && request.body.email !== user.email)
         {
            request.formValidate('email', 'Email not valid').isNotEmpty().isEmail();
            request.formValidate('email', 'Email already used').isUnique(User, () => {
                if (request.formIsValid)
                {
                    user.email = request.body.email;
                    request.user.connect(user);
                    console.log(request.session);
                    User.update(user, () => {
                        request.flash('success', 'Email updated');
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        if (request.body.new_password !== undefined && request.body.new_password !== '')
        {
            request.formValidate('new_password', 'Password is not valid.').isNotEmpty().isLength(6, 255).isGoodPassword();
            request.formValidate('new_password', 'Password does not match').isEqualTo(request.body.new_password_conf);

            if (request.formIsValid)
            {
                user.password = request.body.new_password;
                User.update(user, () => {
                    request.flash('success', 'Password changed!');
                }, true);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        request.flash('error', 'Bad Old password');
    }
    response.redirect('/u/profile');
});
```

[Full code here](https://github.com/Snosky/matcha-42/) (you can find this part in 'routes/user.js')

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the mean of `asynchone` in your case and where exactly you stuck?

Comment: I mean asynchronous sorry. My problem is on the 2 User.update callback, the request.flash is executed too late and when the page refresh the messages don't show because they're not created.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with asynchronous callbacks. You will need to have your response in every possible path because your catch-all redirect ignores asynchronous calls.

```
router.post('/changeCredentials', isConnected, (request, response) => {
     var user = User.formJSON(request.session.user);

     if (User.hashPassword(request.body.old_password, user.salt) === user.password)
     {
         if (request.body.email !== undefined && request.body.email !== user.email)
         {
            request.formValidate('email', 'Email not valid').isNotEmpty().isEmail();
            request.formValidate('email', 'Email already used').isUnique(User, () => {
                if (request.formIsValid)
                {
                    user.email = request.body.email;
                    request.user.connect(user);
                    console.log(request.session);
                    User.update(user, () => {
                        request.flash('success', 'Email updated');
                        response.redirect('/u/profile');
                    });
                    return;
                }
                response.redirect('/u/profile');
            });
            return;
        }

        if (request.body.new_password !== undefined && request.body.new_password !== '')
        {
            request.formValidate('new_password', 'Password is not valid.').isNotEmpty().isLength(6, 255).isGoodPassword();
            request.formValidate('new_password', 'Password does not match').isEqualTo(request.body.new_password_conf);

            if (request.formIsValid)
            {
                user.password = request.body.new_password;
                User.update(user, () => {
                    request.flash('success', 'Password changed!');
                    response.redirect('/u/profile');
                }, true);
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        request.flash('error', 'Bad Old password');
    }
    response.redirect('/u/profile');
});
```

The above code show a callback-style approach. A more elegant solution can be created with Promises and generators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with this we can't change email and password in one submission.